# Click Event on a Stroke of the Shape(arc) doesn't work

Tags: kineticjs

Using KineticJS, a click event on a stoke of the shape(in my case arc) doesn't fire at all.

my code is there  http://jsfiddle.net/mPsfm/

**js**

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(canvas) {

            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            var startAngle = 0;
            var endAngle = 135 * Math.PI / 180;
            ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, startAngle, endAngle, false);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
});

arc.on('click', function() {
    alert("click detected");
 });

layer.add(arc);
stage.add(layer);
```

How can I make this work well?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mPsfm/3/

you were missing one little line:

```
 canvas.fillStroke(this);
```

This makes your custom shape function:

```
 var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(canvas) {

        var ctx = canvas.getContext();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        var startAngle = 0;
        var endAngle = 135 * Math.PI / 180;
        ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        canvas.fillStroke(this);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Ooops... This actually doesn't work in the way I expected.
Click event fires on the filled area, but not on the stroke itself....
Any idea?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mPsfm/2/ Yeah, put the custom drawHitFunc function to include the line width: ctx.arc(50, 50, 40+ctx.lineWidth, startAngle, endAngle, false);

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
I confirmed a click on the stroke fires!
But Can I make the trigger ONLY on the stroke? not on the filled area.

Comment: Not easily, the way you define the shape, you are essentially creating a wedge, you would have to find a way to calculate the Exact corner points of the shape to create a custom hit function. A new release of kineticjs in the future might have an arc only shape with hit function you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, this is a hack, but it gets you pretty much what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mPsfm/3/

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your great work!! I really hope to see a new version of kineticjs with the future I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to EliteOctagon.

the final code is here!

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(canvas) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            var startAngle = 0;
            var endAngle = 135 * Math.PI / 180;
            ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, startAngle, endAngle, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            canvas.fillStroke(this);
        },
    drawHitFunc: function(canvas) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            var startAngle = 0;
            var endAngle = 135 * Math.PI / 180;
            ctx.arc(50, 50, 40+ctx.lineWidth, startAngle, endAngle, false);
            ctx.lineTo(50*Math.cos(endAngle)+40,50*Math.sin(endAngle)+40);
            ctx.lineTo(50*Math.cos(endAngle/2)+40,50*Math.sin(endAngle/2)+40);
            ctx.lineTo(50*Math.cos(startAngle)+40,50*Math.sin(startAngle)+40);
            ctx.stroke();
            canvas.fillStroke(this);
        }
});

arc.on('click', function() {
    alert("click detected");
});


layer.add(arc);
stage.add(layer);
```