# Multiple arcs in canvas with click events

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

Problem :

Trying to create a layout looking like this one below where each portion is clickable and has separate entity.

[image]

Tried solution and problems with it :

create arc with canvas. Have to add the arc with stroke. Stroke is not clickable. Tried hacks from other answers but they don't seem to work.

[Click Event on a Stroke of the Shape(arc) doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434407/click-event-on-a-stroke-of-the-shapearc-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of drawing with arcs, how about this:

**use Wedges instead of Arcs**

- Draw the 3 outside shapes as Wedges and put them on a layer#1.
- Draw the 10 inside shapes as Wedges and put them on another layer#2 above layer#1.
- Draw the center circle as a Circle and put it on another layer#3 above layer#1 & layer#2.
- Attach on.(“click”) to each individual wedge.

Layering will give you the visual "nesting" effect your looking for.

Layering will give you proper click control over each wedge-piece.

Comment: You, sir, are awesome! Thanks a ton! :) I was using wrong element all this while. Should have taken Geometry lessons seriously.